# How to fix ENOENT: no such file or directory?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3

I am writing node js code to upload a picture to my Google Drive from Raspberry Pi

I have tried to upload the image file produced in the same folder. Node js seems to ignore the file. It always returns ENOENT although the file is present. I have verified the existence of the file manually. The path and the filename are correct. I have also verified by printing the filename to the console and it seems to match.

```
    var fileName1 = Date.now();
    const path = require('path');
    const fs1 = require('fs');
    var fN = fileName1+".jpg";
    console.log("Only filename : "+fN);
    const finalPath = path.join(__dirname, fN);
    console.log("Final filename : "+finalPath);
    var media = {
            mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            //PATH OF THE FILE FROM YOUR COMPUTER
            body: fs1.createReadStream(finalPath)
    };
```

**Output**

```
Only filename : 1571724785329.jpg
Final filename : /home/pi/nodecode/1571724785329.jpg
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,open
'/home/pi/nodecode/1571724785329.jpg'
```

Comment: Do you check permissions for the dir/file ?

Comment: try to run the app with `sudo` command if the issue resolved try to change the path to accessible path for the node process to access it

Comment: @Lucek: Yes, the file has Read and Exec permission for all

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair : Do you mean run node as sudo ?

Comment: yes example `sudo npm start`

Comment: Try with relative path like `./1571724785329.jpg`

Comment: Your Code seems to work for me. The only problem I see is in the way you are creating a file name.. There is no chance the filename is going to be same as Date.Now() no matter how you generate it previosuly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot everyone for sharing their views and try to work out the answer for me. I found the problem. The file was not created at that instant when nodejs was trying to locate the file. The file creation and upload was happening parallel. So I used python instead of nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems to work for me. The only problem I see is in the way you are creating a file name.. There is no chance the filename is going to be the same as Date.Now() no matter how you generate it previously.

Thus the sequence of code execution is the only possible cause for your problem. For example, the file you expect to load in the readable stream is not yet created when the code to create a read stream is executing.

TRY

Debugging the code execution sequence and find out if the file is created before or after this piece of code is being executed `fs1.createReadStream(finalPath)`

```
var fileName1 = "wf";
const path = require('path');
const fs1 = require('fs');
var fN = fileName1 + ".jpg";
console.log("Only filename : " + fN);
const finalPath = path.join(__dirname, fN);
console.log("Final filename : " + finalPath);
var media = {
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    //PATH OF THE FILE FROM YOUR COMPUTER
    body: fs1.createReadStream(finalPath)
};

console.log(media);
```

The Output I got.

```
Only filename : wf.jpg
Final filename : D:\dir1\dir2\myproject\wf.jpg
{ mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
  body:
   ReadStream {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 65536,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
     mode: 438,
     start: undefined,
     end: Infinity,
     autoClose: true,
     pos: undefined,
     bytesRead: 0,
     closed: false } }
```